# How to find integers $a$, $b$ so that $\sqrt{2a^2} = b$

Tags: geometry

How can I find some integers $a$, $b$ so that $\sqrt{2a^2} = b$?

I want this so I can make a right angle triangle with two sides the same, and all sides have integer length. I tried the integers up to $10$ but none of them have $2\cdot\text{integer}^2$ that I recognise as a square number.

Cheers.

Comment: You can't make such a right triangle since the square root of $2$ is irrational.

Comment: The only solution is $(a,b)=(0,0)$.

Comment: There is a general formula to find all possible sets of integers that can be sides of a right triangle. Would that be useful to you?

Comment: That sounds very interesting. Where would I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$\sqrt{2a^2} = b\implies a\sqrt2 = b\implies \sqrt 2 = \frac ab$$ which is impossible since [$\sqrt2$ is irrational](https://www.homeschoolmath.net/teaching/proof_square_root_2_irrational.php). Hence **with the exception of $a=b=0$**, no such integers exist.

Answer (score 3):

Since there is no rational number whose square is $2$ there is no square that's twice a square. But you can get as close as you like.
$$
2 \times 5^2 = 50 = 7^2 + 1,
$$
$$
2 \times 12^2 = 288 =  19^2 -1,
$$
$$
2 \times 29^2 =   41^2 +1,
$$
and so on.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2

Answer (score 2):

This question is similar to the proof that $\sqrt2$ is irrational.  $\sqrt{2a^2}=b$ gives $\sqrt2a=b$.  Then $2a^2=b$, which is not possible when $a$ and $b$ are integers.  Of course $a=0, b=0$ would work here, but we probably assuming that $a\ne b$.